# C++ : Read form text file and convert to int problem?

Tags: c++, string

I have this code that reads from marks.txt file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string name,result;
  int number1;
  ifstream myfile ("marks.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( !myfile.eof() )
    {
      getline (myfile,name,'\t');
      getline (myfile,result,'\t');
      stringstream(result) >> number1;
      cout << number1;


    }

    myfile.close();

  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
}
```

with my marks.txt file consists of:

```
john 20
```

But when i ran the program. Number1 output is 36. How can i convert result string to int correctly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you're passing `\t` (tab character) as the delimiter to `getline`. Are you sure you are using a tab in your input file? If you use a space or any other character, all the input will go into `name` and your `result` will be empty, which will leave `number1` undefined. I suspect that's the reason you're getting 36 out of nowhere.

Comment: Yeah. I kinda miss that. Thanks